# EntityFramework changing my query - EntityCommandExecutionException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm getting a '`EntityCommandExecutionException`' and

> An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.

with an inner message of

> Invalid column name 'Department_ID'

This seems to be the query executed from this line of code:

```
List<Employee> _employees = employeeContext.Employees.ToList();
```

```sql
SELECT     [Extent1].[EmployeeID] AS [EmployeeID],
 [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name],
 [Extent1].[Gender] AS [Gender],
 [Extent1].[City] AS [City],
 [Extent1].[DepartmentID] AS [DepartmentID],
 [Extent1].[DateOfBirth] AS [DateOfBirth],
 [Extent1].[Department_ID] AS [Department_ID]
FROM [dbo].[tblEmployee] AS [Extent1]
```

This is wrong considering there is no Department_ID, I have no idea where it is getting this from. This is the Employee class model:

```
[Table("tblEmployee")]
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}

[Table("tblDepartment")]
public class Department
{
    public Int16 ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Not sure what to do. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using CodeFirst to generate your tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Department_ID is coming by virtue of the relationship in your Department class. You have a List Employees there which automatically assumes a column called Department_ID in your Employee table.

What you need to do is add a virtual property called Department in your Employee table instead of adding the DepartmentID

```
[Table("tblEmployee")]
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

If you need to maintain the column name as DepartmentID or you need access to the property DepartmentID in code, then you need to use the ForeignKey attribute as shown below:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DepartmentID")]
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

I would also recommend that you maintain the List as virtual.